# the task is getting executed for last value only in grunt custom task

Tags: gruntjs

While executing grunt custom task I am iterating a loop, inside the loop I am calling a grunt task while calling I set values using current loop value to the task but when loop execute for alliteration it is setting last value of array always.

```
var productionUrl = "http://www.abc.de";
var phantomPagesPath = {
    "index": "/index.php",
    "search": "/Suche?searchString=test",
    "warenkorb": "/warenkorb",
    "product": "/4-ecksofa",
    "cms": "/content/25-service",
    "category": "/bestellung",
    "pageNotFound": "/404"
};

grunt.initConfig({`phantomas: {
        prod: {
            options: {
                options: {
                    'timeout': 30
                },
                buildUi: true
            }
        }
    }`});`

grunt.registerTask('fantomas', 'Custome Phantomas task', function () {        

    var done = this.async();
    var pageUrl = '';
    var location = '';
    for (var page in phantomPagesPath) {            
        pageUrl = '';
        location = '';
        if (phantomPagesPath.hasOwnProperty(page)) {
            pageUrl = productionUrl + phantomPagesPath[page];
            location = './public/phantomas/' + page + "/";
            console.log("process started for: " + pageUrl);
            console.log("location: " + location);
            grunt.config.set('phantomas.options.url', pageUrl);
            grunt.config.set('phantomas.options.indexPath', location);
            grunt.task.run('phantomas');                
        }            
    }
    done();
});
```

Now Output I am getting

process started for: http://www.abc.de/index.php
location: ./public/phantomas/index/

process started for: http://www.abc.de/Suche?searchString=test
location: ./public/phantomas/search/

process started for: http://www.abc.de/warenkorb
location: ./public/phantomas/warenkorb/

process started for: http://www.abc.de/4-ecksofa
location: ./public/phantomas/product/

process started for: http://www.abc.de/content/25-service
location: ./public/phantomas/cms/

process started for: http://www.abc.de/bestellung
location: ./public/phantomas/category/

process started for: http://www.abc.de/404
location: ./public/phantomas/pageNotFound/

Running "phantomas:prod" (phantomas) task
PHANTOMAS EXECUTION(S) STARTED.

Task are getting executed for all number of entries but the data sent for task is the last entry from loop "pageNotFound",

I mean this process is working 7 times but on each process, it is taking last value of loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching a lot I came up with the solution that inspite of calling

```
grunt.task.run('phantomas');
```

Within the foreach loop, it should be called outside the loop which means the task is going to be executed for one time only. So for this, we need to increase make tasks/target within the task for which I did following code:

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-phantomas');
var phantomPagesPath = {
    "index": "/index.php",
    "search": "/Suche?searchString=test",
    "warenkorb": "/warenkorb",
    "product": "/4-ecksofa",
    "cms": "/content/25-service",
    "category": "/bestellung",
    "pageNotFound": "/404"
};
  grunt.initConfig({
   phantomas: {            
        //For Executing this task run: grunt fantomas
    },
```

`});`

```
// Register customer task for phantomas
grunt.registerTask('fantomas', 'Custome Phantomas task', function () {
    var done = this.async();
    var pageUrl = '';
    var location = '';
    for (var page in phantomPagesPath) {
        pageUrl = productionUrl + phantomPagesPath[page];
        location = './public/phantomas/' + page + "/";
        grunt.config.set('phantomas.'+page+'.options.url', pageUrl);
        grunt.config.set('phantomas.'+page+'.options.indexPath', location);
        grunt.config.set('phantomas.'+page+'.options.buildUi', true);
        grunt.config.set('phantomas.'+page+'.options.options.timeout', 30);
        var pageUrl = '';
        var location = '';
    }
    grunt.task.run('phantomas');
    done();
});
```

Now run

```
grunt fantomas
```